# Prolog- Appending a list of lists

Tags: list, prolog, dcg

My database follows this format:

`aminotodna (Amincoacid, [DNA sequence]).`

Here are a few examples from the database:

```
aminotodna(a,[g,c,a]).
aminotodna(a,[g,c,c]).
aminotodna(a,[g,c,g]).
aminotodna(a,[g,c,t]).
aminotodna(c,[t,g,c]).
aminotodna(c,[t,g,t]).
aminotodna(d,[g,a,c]).
aminotodna(d,[g,a,t]).
aminotodna(e,[g,a,a]).
aminotodna(e,[g,a,g]).
aminotodna(f,[t,t,c]).
aminotodna(f,[t,t,t]).
```

Some aminoacids have multiple DNA sequences.
Here is my question, so in a given list of amino acids for example `[d,c,e,f]`, how can I append their DNA sequences together and give all combinations, as some have more than one sequence.

If it was just two I could do it, it'd just be

```
listamino(X,Y) :-
    aminotodna(X,L),
    aminotodna(Y,M),
    append(L,M,Z),
    print(Z).
```

hitting `;` gives all combinations.

I've tired doing it with a list, but this is my attempt, and it didnt work:

```
listamino([]).
listamino([H|T]) :-
    aminotodna(H,L),
    aminotodna(T,M),
    append(L,M,X),
    print(X).

listamino(T).
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the behavior you want, based on your sample data?

Comment: @ScottHunter So if I wrote listamino([a,c,e]). It'd append the DNA sequence, So the result would be [g,c,a,t,g,c,g,a,a] and every other combination

Comment: It is really bad manners to completely remove the contents of the question that you have gotten answers for. This invalidates the answers and nullifies the efforts of whoever has answered.

Answer (score 3):

When describing lists with Prolog, always consider using DCG notation for convenience and clarity. For example, using a subset of your examples, I first use DCG rules to describe the correspondence (note that I am using a name that makes sense in all directions):

```
amino_dna(a) --> [g,c,a].
amino_dna(a) --> [g,c,c].
amino_dna(c) --> [t,g,c].
amino_dna(c) --> [t,g,t].
```

an then I again use DCG rules to describe the concatenation of such lists:

```
aminos([]) --> [].
aminos([A|As]) --> amino_dna(A), aminos(As).
```

Sample query:

```
?- phrase(aminos([a,c]), As).
As = [g, c, a, t, g, c] ;
As = [g, c, a, t, g, t] ;
As = [g, c, c, t, g, c] ;
etc.
```

No `append/3`, no additional variables, no additional arguments, **no nonsense**. Use [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg)!

Answer (score 1):

You need an extra parameter to keep track of the current combination:

```
; invoke a version of listamino which tracks the current combination of DNA sequences, which is initially empty
listamino(X) :-
    listamino(X,[]). 

; If there are no ore aminos, print the DNA seq list, and we're done 
listamino([],X) :-
    print(X).

; Otherwise, append the DNA for the first amino to our list, and process the rest of the mains
listamino([H|T],X) :-
    aminotodna(H,L),
    append(X,L,X2),
    listamino(T,X2).
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. But if you can just clarify which parameter is keeping track of the current combination?

Comment: The one I added; the one that gets printed; the second one.

Comment: I'm really struggling to understand this. What is ' listamino(X) :-
    listamino(X,[]). ' doing? and why is there an X after the list in listamino([H|T],X) ?